Confusion matrix for PLSDA in R: "Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels."
I am trying to run a Partial Least Squares Discriminant Analysis (PLSDA) in R, followed by a prediction and confusion matrix, using the mdatools package. The mdatools::plsda function works normally, as does stats::predict, but I have been experiencing difficulties with caret::confusionMatrix.
Here is a reproducible example:
library(tidyverse)
library(mdatools)
library(caret)

#GetData

data(iris)

#Sampling 50/50 for train and valid

set.seed(2000)
Train <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% sample_frac(.5, replace = FALSE)
Valid <- anti_join(iris, Train)

#Separating categorical variable from numerical variables

PLSDA_Response = as.matrix(Train[,5])
PLSDA_Predictors = as.matrix(Train[,c(1:4)])

Predict_Response = as.matrix(Valid[,5])
Predict_Predictors = as.matrix(Valid[,c(1:4)])

#Run PLS-DA

pls_comp <- mdatools::plsda(PLSDA_Predictors, as.factor(PLSDA_Response), ncomp = 1)

#Run the prediction

pls_comp_predict <- stats::predict(pls_comp, Predict_Predictors)

#Run the Confusion Matrix

pls_CM <- caret::confusionMatrix(pls_comp_predict, as.factor(Predict_Response))


The message I receive is: Error: data and reference should be factors with the same levels.
Can someone help me, please? Thanks! :)

Below, I provide a possible solution to your classification problem using PLSDA.
# Run PLS-DA
pls_comp <- mdatools::plsda(PLSDA_Predictors, as.factor(PLSDA_Response), ncomp = 1)

# Run the prediction
pls_comp_predict <- mdatools:::predict.pls(pls_comp, x=Predict_Predictors)
y_pred <- pls_comp_predict$y.pred[,1,1:3]

# Distribution of the predicted outcome across the three classes 
# (virginica, versicolor, setosa) and two reasonable cutoffs
boxplot(y_pred[,1]~as.factor(Predict_Response))
abline(a=0.25, b=0, col="red", lty=2)
abline(a=-0.9, b=0, col="red", lty=2)


# Run the Confusion Matrix
class_pred <- cut(y_pred[,1], breaks=c(-2,-.9,0.25,2), 
                  labels=c("virginica","versicolor","setosa"))
class_ref  <- factor(Predict_Response, levels=c("virginica","versicolor","setosa"))

pls_CM <- caret::confusionMatrix(class_pred, class_ref)
print(pls_CM)

Here is the confusion matrix obtained:
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

            Reference
Prediction   virginica versicolor setosa
  virginica         21          1      0
  versicolor         3         24      0
  setosa             0          0     25

Overall Statistics
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.9459          
                 95% CI : (0.8673, 0.9851)
    No Information Rate : 0.3378          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.9189          
                                          
 Mcnemar`s Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: virginica Class: versicolor Class: setosa
Sensitivity                    0.8750            0.9600        1.0000
Specificity                    0.9800            0.9388        1.0000
Pos Pred Value                 0.9545            0.8889        1.0000
Neg Pred Value                 0.9423            0.9787        1.0000
Prevalence                     0.3243            0.3378        0.3378
Detection Rate                 0.2838            0.3243        0.3378
Detection Prevalence           0.2973            0.3649        0.3378
Balanced Accuracy              0.9275            0.9494        1.0000

